# shopping cart plugin development

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, options

I'm developing a new shopping cart plugin for WordPress. At a point, how to save orders, I am stuck, sort of confused. Actually I am not sure whether I should save order through options api or create a new post type to handle Orders. Which approach is the best?? This plugin is not too complicated, it just handles book's shop, so the parameters/options for product are limited.

thanks @Nilambar for your suggestion, if that is the case I have few more questions:

How to prevent admin to create new orders manually( disabling 'add new oreder' )?

And one more thing - Order's post doesn't need title and editor, it will have its own options like order value, order no. etc. but if I don't specify title or editor param in supports array, it shows both by default on order post screen (on new and edit both screens).

What I am experiencing is I have to provide at least one title or editor in supports arrray to disable another otherwise it doesn't work. I want to disable both.

Comment: I would recommend using Post Type for order. Afterwards it will be easy to add extra information to Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass boolean `false` to `supports` to have post type support nothing at all.

However note that:

- you might run into issues with saving "empty" posts (not having one of title/editor/excerpt)
- likely you still want it to support `custom-fields` at least, rather than nothing at all